# Prometheus alert: pagerduty incident name / summary

Tags: prometheus

This is already asked [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-to-change-pagerduty-incident-name) but I dont see a response hence asking again.

For the prometheus alerts shown in pagerduty the summary text format seems to be:

```
[FIRING:1]<alertname>(label label-value label label-value ... )
```

How do I change this to:

```
[FIRING:1]<alertname>(<Annotations: SUMMARY>)
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's only one value, you can access the summary annotation with `{{ .CommonAnnotations.SUMMARY }}`

See https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/notification_examples/#accessing-annotations-in-commonannotations